# .submit doesn't work on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I created custom form for fast reply (`.append`), now I want to use ajax for submit reply without reloading, I tried `.on('submit', function(e)...` which doesn't work (tried event delegation also). Now I tried `.on('click', function(e)...` and this works - don't know why.

```
$("#newpost").on('click', '.send', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
$("#newpost").on('submit', '.send', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Appended form:

```
<form id="newpost" method="post" action="/forum/addpost/"+ id +"/"+ rek +" name="newpost">
  <div class="editor" align="left">
    <textarea name="post" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
   <div class="submit" align="right">
     <input class="send" value="." title="Send" type="submit">
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So why `.on('submit'..)` doesn't work even if I use event delegation?
Thank you

Comment: Try to use jQuery('body').on('submit', 'form#newpost", function() {
  //Your job.
});

Comment: @Nidecker Is the form appended also?

Comment: @tilz0R - no, did not work, I have preventdefault inside function, but form is submitted normally

Comment: @Curt - yes, jQuery("div.go_top").append( postform ); (form is in postform variable). And sending works fine, form is created correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because you have conflicting name to textarea(name="post") with the form properties.

As from jquery documentation:
[jquery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see DOMLint.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is problem. Unfortunately I can't change name attribute so I need to use .on('click'..) method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you append the whole form dynamically then you'll have to attach the submit listener to something that already exists when the page loads. Something like this:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#newpost', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT:
I might have misread the question. The part you said doesn't work cant work because you don't submit a ".click" button, but the form that your ".click" button is in.

Answer (score 0):

The right form is

```
$( "#newpost" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Later edit:
I understood now what you want.Try a new approach.Presuming that id is 23 and rek is value "add" you have the following:

HTML

```
<div class="editor" align="left">
    <textarea name="post" cols="50" rows="5" id="post"></textarea>
   <div class="submit" align="right">
     <input class="send" value="." title="Send" type="button" id="23"  data-rek="add">
   </div>
  </div>
```

JS ( can be used in external file also):

```
    //get the answer based on id-s and classes
    $("body").on("click", ".send", function() {

//get what is at attribute id of the clicked link 
        var ID=$(this).attr("id");

//get the text from the form with id "fasttext"
        var thetext = $("#post").val();

//take the value of rek ( don't know what means :) )
        var therek = $(this).attr("data-rek");


//create the string that will be posted
        var theString = 'post=' + thetext;

//post the form using ajax and without reloading the page
            $.ajax(
              {
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/forum/addpost/"+ id +"/"+ therek,
                  data: theString,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html)
                  {
    //do what you want to do as success - html is the returning response
    //you can also make this div disappear or display a success message

    }
              });

    });

    });
```

Comment: This is only if the form is also not posted

Comment: I tried .submit also, only working option is still .on('click'...)

Comment: I understand now. I updated my answer with a similar approach to make what you want happen. I have a typo there: instead of  var ID=$(this).attr("id"); write  var id=$(this).attr("id"); with lower case: id

Comment: @Vas Hanea - No, no, I just wanted to know why .on('submit'..) is not working (it is because name conflict). And rek and id variables are already defined (and they have nothing in common with attributes). Also ajax works fine. anyway, thanks ;-)

Comment: Point is, I'm tired of "reply system" on one site. Scroll down, click on reply, redirect to editor, write your reply, click on Send, redirect on success page a then redirect bact in topic. So I make this userscript (for greasemonkey) - adds editor at the bottom and after submit there is no redirect now. Form is created by .append and reply is send by ajax

Comment: Then use <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="send" >Send form</a> if you are using ajax for sending the form values. And make a button look like style for this href.

Answer (score -2):

May be problem is here

```
<div class="submit" align="right">
     <input class="send" value="." title="Send" type="submit">
```

try to remove `class="submit"` from `div` tag

```
<div align="right">
         <input class="send" value="." title="Send" type="submit">
```

Comment: No, this is fine but there is another name conflict and that' the problem